# the content cannot be displayed in a frame sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365

I am trying to open a modal pop up using the following JavaScript:

```
if (this.Context != null && !this.Context.Items.Contains(SPRequestModule.AllowFramingFlag)) {
    this.Context.Items.Add(SPRequestModule.AllowFramingFlag, "1");
}

var options = { url: "https://eeeee/Lists/ProjectLibrary/NewForm.aspx", width: 400, height: 300 };
//enter code here
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);`
```

I also added the site to the trusted sites zone.  I get the following error

> the content cannot be displayed in a frame sharepoint.

I also tried to open a iframe using

```
window.top.location.href = "https://eeeee/Lists/ProjectLibrary/NewForm.aspx"
```

Still get the  same result..

Answer (score 1):

use the below script in CEWP:

```
<a onclick="modalcall()" href="#">New Request</a>
<script type="text/javascript">function modalcall() { 
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
    url: "NewForm.aspx", 
    title: "New Form", 
    allowMaximize: true, 
    showClose: true, 
    dialogReturnValueCallback: refreshCallback
    }); 
}; 
function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);}</script>
```