# How to display a page in Modal popup in SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modal-dialog

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(yourFunction, 'sp.js');

        function yourFunction() 
        { 

      var options = { url: 'https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/MyApp/Pages/Default.aspx', title: 'Policy', width: 900, height: 400,dialogReturnValueCallback: onPopUpCloseCallBack };
                               SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);


         }

         function onPopUpCloseCallBack(result, returnValue) 
         {
             if(result== SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
             {

                  SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
                  var sId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("you clicked ok");
                  SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(sId, 'green');
             }
            else if(result== SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel)
             {
                 SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
                 var sId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("you clicked cancel");
                 SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(sId, 'yellow');
             }
        }
```

I have used the above code to display a page named **Default.aspx** in a modal popup but unfortunately it gives me following error

[image]

Am I doing something wrong Or its not possible to display a page in modal popup in SharePoint Online?

The same code works perfectly on SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use below script in CEWP

```
<a onclick="modalcall()" href="#">New Request</a>
<script type="text/javascript">function modalcall() { 
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
    url: "NewForm.aspx", 
    title: "New Form", 
    allowMaximize: true, 
    showClose: true, 
    dialogReturnValueCallback: refreshCallback
    }); 
}; 
function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);}</script>
```

[the content cannot be displayed in a frame sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115306/the-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/The-Content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-Display-another-SharePoint-WebApplication-inside-an-iFrame-of-our-SharePoint-Site

@luckydeveloper I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, use a html page if it's possible, or add `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server" />` to your aspx page.